# prestashop - a code to add the new user or customer

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I'm trying to analyze AuthController.php file or modules which integrate Presta with other systems but it fails..

Do you have any solutions or pieces of code to easily do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I've got one that's work for me:

```
include '../config/config.inc.php';  // path ti the config file
   $cookie = new Cookie('ps', '', 3600);

Db::getInstance()->Execute("INSERT INTO `ps_customer` VALUES (NULL,$gengre,1,'$tempname','$tempsurname','$email','".md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passNew)."',NOW(),NULL,0,NULL,NULL,0,'ba27e0ac14389d8feb89c3c9e7594464',NULL,1,0,0,NOW(),NOW())");
```

maybe It can help someone

Comment: Hello,I have the same problem. I am using the insert statement below INSERT INTO `ps_customer`(`active`, `id_gender`,  `email`,`passwd`, `lastname`, `firstname`, `newsletter`,`optin`) VALUES 
(1,9, "sahinfundabas@yahoo.com",  md5('32TTTTTTTTTVGKGRRRRRRRRRW5rrrrrrrrrrLr94ooooooP2kfpQgCc6'+'27121980'),"şahinbaş","funda",1,1);
 Ofcourse I changed the key before pasting here. My problem is I can not login with the email and password which is 27121980
Quardas do you have an idea how I can fix this ?

Comment: md5 sql some time is not same as php